# Populating the spinner and Rotation of screen not causing the activity instance to be destroyed

Tags: android

I'm trying the populate the spinners with the String values. Then I select the value from the spinner, on rotation of the screen , I'm not seeing the activity instance to be destroyed as and the content remains intact. Instead, since the system configuration has changed from horizontal view to vertical and vice versa, the activity should have been destroyed.

Could someone explain how its working?

Comment: Did you have `android:configChanges` param in `<activity>` tag of manifest?

Comment: no i dont have in the manifest file